# One vSphere Server - Two ESXi hosts - Two Separate Subnets - One NIC

Tags: vmware, vsphere

I have two physical servers - Server One (10.7.1.25) and Server Two (192.168.1.25).  I plan on using the vCenter Converter to convert these two physical servers to two virtual machines hosted by vSphere.

The problem that I am not fully understanding is how a single physical NIC on the vSphere Server is going to allow client workstations on the network to see the two ESXi servers at 10.7.1.25 and 192.168.1.25 within the vSphere Server.  I see the configuration of vmkernel ports, vswtich and vmnics within vSphere to separate the servers.  But from the vSphere Server to the physical network...that's where I am not seeing technical information that fills in the blanks.

Am I using vlan tagging within a managed switch to route to 10.7.1.25 and 192.168.1.25?  Or should there be two NICs in the vSphere Server?  If there is only one NIC, what is telling the physical network the computers on 10.7.1.X see the server at 10.7.1.25 and those computers on 192.168.1.X see the server at 192.168.1.25?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when using an ESXi host with a single NIC, you will want to be using VLAN tags for this situation. You'll want to create a portgroup for each of the VLAN tags you intend to use, then assign the designated portgroup to the NIC for each VM.